# How to deploy a war in an specific path jboss as 7.4 using jenkins and jboss-as?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss, maven-plugin

im trying to deploy a war file to jboss-AS 7.4, but when i run the deploy, the plugin deploy the war file genetated by the plugin,what i need is that the plugin deploys a war file in a specific directory of my system, this is my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ss</groupId>
<artifactId>ss</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ss</name>
<description>uses the pom to deploy to Jboss AS 7 with jenkins</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <hostName>localhost</hostName>
    <jbossUser>user</jbossUser>
    <jbossPass>admin</jbossPass>
    <warName>ss</warName>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
                <hostname>${hostName}</hostname>
                <username>${jbossUser}</username>
                <password>${jbossPass}</password>
                <port>10000</port>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>${warName}.war</fileName>
                </fileNames>
                <name>ss.war</name>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

assuming that the war file is in the same directory as the pom, how can i make this work?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found a solution and apparently the problem be really small, the problem was that i was using a different property inside the configuration tags, this is the pom that worked for me:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cc</groupId>
<artifactId>cc</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>cc</name>
<description>uses the pom to deploy to Jboss AS 7 with jenkins</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>pass</password>
                <port>10000</port>
                <filename>mywar.war</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the change made is that I delete the tags **fileNames** and **fileName** and add the property **filename**, here you can specify the path to the war file to be deployed in the server ignoring the generated war in the target directory.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the plugin documentation, it looks like you have to set the targetDir to the target directory where you want your application to be deployed [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/7.4.Final/deploy-mojo.html)

Default: ${project.build.directory}/

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.Final</version>
        <configuration>
            <force>true</force>
            <hostname>${hostName}</hostname>
            <username>${jbossUser}</username>
            <password>${jbossPass}</password>
            <port>10000</port>
            <fileNames>
                <fileName>${warName}.war</fileName>
            </fileNames>
            <name>ss.war</name>
            <targetDir>src/custom/path/</targetDir>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, adding the targetDir property only makes that the war generated be located in the specified path, now i have a solution, i´ll post it in a moment, thanks @Grauzone